# InvalidOperationException: different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

I am using ASP.NET Core 7.

I have a Users Controller to manage Identity Users as follows:

```
namespace Aqbel.Controllers;

public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public UsersController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var users = await _userManager.Users.Select(user => new UserViewModel
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Email = user.Email,
            Roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result
        }).ToListAsync();
        return View(users);
    }
}
```

Index View as follows

```
@model IEnumerable<UserViewModel>

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Users"; }

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<a asp-action="Add" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</a>

<table class="table table-striped mt-4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th> Email</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <th>Manage Roles</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                <td>@user.LastName</td>
                <td>@user.UserName</td>
                <td>@user.Email</td>
                <td>@string.Join(" , ", user.Roles.ToList())</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="ManageRoles" asp-route- userId="@user.Id">Roles</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-userId="@user.Id">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there anything wrong in the codes to get this type of error?

Comment: `Roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result` - problem here. Should be something like this: `Roles = user.Roles`. If this doesn't work, then show the `DbContext` code and the `User` and `Role` entities.

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions for this error. I suspect the bug in this case is `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result`, which tries to execute one query in the middle of another. Why use that instead of `user.Roles`? EF Core will see this and include each user's roles

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov the code seems to be using the [ASP.NET Core Identity classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in which case `user.Roles` is already available

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but user.Roles do not work

Comment: To add some user information, we are using a new Identity class called ApplicationUser, which inherits from the Microsoft IdentityUser, we also developed a UserViewModel in order to use it  to view the user's data
To get the list of users who will be displayed on the Index page as well as the roles that have been assigned to each user, we used the commands listed above. So in order to get the list of roles we used this command 
Roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result 
Sometimes the code is work properly and get the list shown, but the mentioned error frequently occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.Result` on a `Task`, which is a blocking call.

```
Roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result <--- problem here
```

We can change Index method like below to fix the issue.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
    
    var userViewModels = new List<UserViewModel>();

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        userViewModels.Add(new UserViewModel
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Email = user.Email,
            Roles = roles
        });
    }

    return View(userViewModels);
}
```